# Using pattern to block some of dynamic URLs in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I'm trying to exclude some of page from indexing. I have search form where you can use some of predefined parameters or user typed queries. I need to block search results that have user-provided querys.

Example URLs:

- `example.com?adv=0&query=&r=0&woj=0&msc=&osk=&osb=&osn=` # index it!
- `example.com?adv=0&query=&r=0&woj=0&msc=&osk=&osb=&osn=` # index it too!
- `example.com?adv=0&query=**USER_QUERY**&r=0&woj=0&msc=&osk=&osb=&osn=` # don't index!

robots.txt:

```
User-Agent: *

Disallow: /example.com?adv=0&query=*&r=0&woj=0&msc=&osk=&osb=&osn=
```

Will asterisk symbol work as I expect? Google will know that asterisk is intended to be linked only with `&query` param and if this param is empty URL should be indexed?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't have a blank line between `User-agent` and `Disallow`.

Comment: Note that the URL path in `Disallow` should not start with the host (`domain.com`).

Comment: Yes, it's just example...

Answer (score 0):

Bing and Google allow wildcards ? * (from https://youtu.be/G29Zt-UH_Ko)